# sharing things too the same app open's up the app again and again and showing in the recent task 2 times

Tags: android, image, share

I have added this in my manifest to make my app visible in the share intent chooser..

```
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- WebRTC Dependencies -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.weone.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.weone.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AnkiTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.weone.android" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->


        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".utilities.network.gcm.gcmservices.GcmNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".utilities.network.gcm.gcmservices.GcmInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".utilities.network.gcm.gcmservices.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AnkiTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.CarouselActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.ChangeNumber"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.HelpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.BlockedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.PayInfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.DrawerActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.AboutUsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.PhoneNumberActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.InviteActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="com.weone.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.activities.SmsDetectActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.CropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.PlayVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".chatcontents.chatactivity.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.NetworkActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.InfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.SettingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".chatcontents.chatactivity.WebRTCViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.PrivacyPolicy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controllers.subactivities.sidedrawer.FaqActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver android:name=".utilities.helpers.receivers.SmsDetector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>      
    </application>


</manifest>
```

But when i am sharing something to my chat section, my app is opening again and again and showing wot or more than two times in recent task. i do not know what i am doing wrong can any one help me out?

Comment: Post the rest of the `<activity>` tag that contains that `<intent-filter>`

Comment: updated the  code :)

Comment: Please post your whole manifest. This looks strange.

Comment: Please do the following: using the command `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` after you have shared something to your chat section and you have your app multiple times in the recent task list. Post the results. This includes a lot of data about the activity stacks and recent tasks and should help to understand what is going on.

Comment: The `Activity` being launched by the "share" action is not your root `Activity`. Depending on how the application that is doing the share launches this `Activity`, it could end up in a new task, it could end up in an existing task (if your app is running), or it could end up in the same task as the app that is doing the share.

Comment: yeah its not a root activity because my root activity is splash but still i am opening the app called drawer activity and in drawer activity only i need the share intent..but when i am delaring the launchmode as a singleinstance the how would i get the intent value which i am sending from my one activity to another ?

Comment: You haven't declared any `Activity` as `launchMode="singleInstance"` and even if you did, it wouldn't be a single-instance `Activity` since you haven't set the `taskAffinity` either. This is a complex problem that most developers do not fully understand. Search SO for some of my answers regardin `launchMode`s and `taskAffinity`. Please post the `adb shell` output so we can help you.